# Measuring the speed of a river

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, raspberry-pi

I already improved my program with the suggestions of @Mast. As requested by him I re-upload the code in English so we can check it out together.

But before I'll explain a little bit what this program does. As my brother is a hydrogeologist, he needed a program that could transform spin of an hydrometric reel into speed ([here](http://www.supsi.ch/ist_en/servizi/idrologia.html) is a brief explanation with a photo under "Measuring with small hydrometric reel"), to calculate the flow of the river.

This has to go on a Raspberry Pi, that he will bring on the field to simplify his work. That's why I chose Python and appJar to do this work.

Here is the code improved as discussed in this other [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191526/appjar-number-pad-and-keyboard):

```
import csv
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #library for raspberry pins
import time
from appJar import gui
l=[]
class measure: #All the measures that needs to be into the csv file
    global l
    def fileName(self):#Station where you do the measures have a code, and we call the filename with that code
        fileName=app.getEntry("e1") +'.csv'
        return fileName
    def vertical(self):#The point where you measure the speed of the river
        vertical=float(app.getEntry("e2"))
        return vertical
    def depthTot(self):
        depthtot=float(app.getEntry("e3"))#The depth of the river where you are doing the measure
        return depthtot
    def edgeDist(self): #Distance from the edge of the river
        e=float(app.getEntry("e2"))
        return e
    def hydroDepth(self): # Depth where you have the hydrometric reel
        hydrodepth=float(app.getEntry("e4"))
        return hydrodepth
    def changeMs(self): #Function that clears the entries for the measures, as you do many measures on the same station
        app.clearEntry("e2")
        app.clearEntry("e3")
        app.clearEntry("e4")
        app.clearLabel("e5")
        app.showButton("Start measure")
        app.setFocus("e2")
    def changeDepth(self): #This clears only the last entry, as if the river is a lot deep you need to do more measures on the same vertical
        prof=float(app.getEntry("e4"))
        v=app.getLabel("e5")
        l.append(prof)
        l.append(v)
        app.clearEntry("e4")
        app.showButton("Start measure")
        app.setFocus("e4")
    def changeStation(self):#Clears all entries, when you change station
        app.clearEntry("e1")
        app.clearEntry("e2")
        app.clearEntry("e3")
        app.clearEntry("e4")
        app.clearLabel("e5")
        app.showButton("Start measure")
        app.setFocus("e1")
    def hydroReel(self): #Gets the size of the Hydrometric reel
        size=app.getOptionBox("HydroReel")
        return size
    def measurementTime(self): #The measure of speed needs to be over a period of time, so you have less error
        t=app.getOptionBox("Secondi misurazione")
        return float(t)

class calculations:
    def speed(self,hydroreel,spin): #this is the function that calculates the speed from the spins of the hydroreel
        v=0
        spin_1s=0
        if spin=='':
            v=''
            return v
        spin=float(spin)
        spin_1s=spin/30
        if spin_1s==0:
            v=0
            return v
        if mulinello=='125':
            if spin_1s<1.98:
                v=(1.93+(31.17*spin_1s))/100
                return v
            elif spin_1s<10.27:
                v=(0.19+(32.05*spin_1s))/100
                return v
            else:
                v=(-14.09+(33,44*spin_1s))/100
                return v
        elif mulinello=='80':
            if spin_1s<1:
                v=(2.8+(31.34*spin_1s))/100
                return v
            else:
                v=(0.82+(33.32*spin_1s))/100
                return v
        elif mulinello=='50':
            if spin_1s<1.74:
                v=(1.23+(24.73*spin_1s))/100
                return v
            else:
                v=(-0.42+(25.68*spin_1s))/100
                return v
        elif mulinello=='30':
            if spin_1s<1.16:
                v=(1.90+(10.57*spin_1s))/100
                return v
            else:
                v=(2.26+(10.26*spin_1s))/100
                return v
    def spinCounter(self,t): #this function measures the spins through raspberry
        spin=input('Inserire numero di spin') # here i used this input for the spins because i don't use the raspberry every time
        final_t = time.time()+t
        return spin
        """GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(32,GPIO.IN)

        #set up a counter
        spin = 0

        #set up a variable for reed activation
        reed_state = 0
        print("Misurazione in corso...")
        t_fine = time.time()+temp_mis
        #while loop until 30s
        while time.time()<t_fine:
        #check if reed newly activated
            if GPIO.input(32) == 1 and reed_state == 0:
                #turn on LED. Set reed_state to 1. Add to counter .
                reed_state = 1
                spin = spin + 1
            #pause to debounce
            time.sleep(.01)
            #check if reed released
            if GPIO.input(32) == 0 and reed_state == 1:
                # set reed_state to 0
                reed_state = 0

            #now that loop has finished, print the final count
        return spin """
def startMeasure(self):     #this is the function triggered to start the measure of speed
        c=calculations()
        m=measure()
        v=c.speed(m.hydroReel(),c.spinCounter(m.measurementTime()))
        v=round(v,4)
        l=[m.hydroDepth(),v]
        app.setLabel("e5",v)
        app.hideButton("Start measure")
file1=''
def insertMeasure(self): #this function inserts all the data into a csv file
    global file1,mis_0,l
    m=measure()
    myFile = open(m.fileName(),'a')
    with myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile,lineterminator='\n')
        if file1!=m.fileName():
            firstLine = ["Vertical", "Edge distance", "Depth"]+["HydroDepth","Speed"]*5
            writer.writerow(firstLine)
            file1=m.fileName()
            mis_0=float(m.edgeDist())
        depth=float(app.getEntry("e4"))
        v=app.getLabel("e5")
        l.append(depth)
        l.append(v)
        writer.writerow([m.vertical(),(m.vertical()-mis_0),m.depthTot()]+l)
        l=[]

def putInto(Button):
    focus=app.getFocus()
    entry=app.getEntry(focus)
    entry=entry+Button
    app.setEntry(focus,entry)
def press(Button):
    putInto(Button)


app=gui()   #this is the grapich core of the program
app.setTitle("Water app")
app.setFont(size=12, family="Calibri")

app.addLabel("l1", "Measures",0,0)
app.addLabel("l2", "Speed",5,0)


app.addEntry("e1",1,0)
app.addEntry("e2",2,0)
app.addEntry("e3",3,0)
app.addEntry("e4",4,0)
app.addLabel("e5","",6,0)

app.addButton("Start measure",startMeasure,6,0)

app.addButton("Inserisci misura",insertMeasure,4,1)
app.addButton("Altra profondità",measure.changeDepth,3,1)
app.addButton("Cambia misura",measure.changeMs,2,1)
app.addButton("Cambia stazione",measure.changeStation,1,1)

app.setEntryDefault("e1", "Station number")
app.setEntryDefault("e2", "Vertical n°")
app.setEntryDefault("e3", "Total depth")
app.setEntryDefault("e4", "Hydro reel distance")
app.setGuiPadding(15, 5)
app.addLabelOptionBox("Reel size", ['125', '80', '50','30'],5,1)
app.addLabelOptionBox("Seconds of measurement", ['15', '30', '60','120','180'],6,1,2)

app.setLabelFont(size=13,weight="bold")
app.setEntryWidths(["e1","e2","e3","e4"], 20)
app.setEntryRelief("e1", "raised")
app.setEntryRelief("e2", "raised")
app.setEntryRelief("e3", "raised")
app.setEntryRelief("e4", "raised")

app.addButtons([["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"],["0",".","O"]],press,1, 2, 3,4)
app.addButtons([["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"],["I","L","M","N"],["P","Q","R","S"],["T","U","V","Z"]],press,1,5,4,5)

app.go()
```

I wanted to ask if there is anything else I could do to improve this little program (could we add the tag appJar to simplify searching?).
EDIT: is it possible to add the data to an excel or Libre office Calc sheet instead of csv? Because it would be more useful.

Comment: Hello! I think many comments from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191526/appjar-number-pad-and-keyboard (including style) apply to this piece of code as well.  Also, all the code in """triple-quoted string""" seems pretty weird...

Comment: In that piece I simply count how many times the reel spins, as it works as a simple on/off switch. I already tested it on the raspberry and it works great. As styling I am currently working on it. @Josay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There's a bunch of style/spacing issues.  I suggest reading PEP8.  That said, if you're the only one maintaining this code, do what you want.
2. Methods of the form:

   ```
   def getSomething(self):
       something=...
       return something
   ```

   are better written just as:

   ```
   def getSomething(self):
       return ...
   ```

   For instance:

   ```
   def fileName(self): #Station where you do the measures have a code, and we call the filename with that code
       return app.getEntry("e1") +'.csv'
   ```
3. Similarly, you can just return expressions instead of having to assign them to a variable first.  There's a lot of:

   ```
   v=...
   return v
   ```

   that could be just:

   ```
   return ...
   ```
4. Class and function documentation is free if you move your comments a little.  If you change that to:

   ```
   def fileName(self):
       """Station where you do the measures have a code, 
           and we call the filename with that code"""
       return app.getEntry("e1") +'.csv'
   ```

   then you can see those comments from the command-line interface via the `help()` command. Also, using triple quotes instead of `#` lets you use multi-line comments.

Comment: I am seeing the styling through pep8. Didn't thought that there were so many rules.

Comment: @LorenzBonat And you can automatically check against some of those rules automatically. For example, there's the [pep8  package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8), and the (inferior) [online check](http://pep8online.com/).

Answer (score 3):

## Classes

I see both too many and too little classes in your code. On one hand, you have the `calculations` class, where the `self` is used nowhere, but on the other hand you have the global variable app, where you do a lot of operations on, and which is changed a lot in your `measure` class. I would change the `measure` class, to do all the operations of the GUI. Since it does no measures any more,

### calculations

There is a lot of repeated code in your speed calculation with just changed constants. This can be done a lot easier using a dict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
HYDROREELS = OrderedDict()
HYDROREELS['125'] = (
    (1.98, 1.93, 31.17),
    (10.28, 0.19, 32.05),
    (float('inf'), -14.09, 33.44),
)
HYDROREELS['80'] = (
    (1, 2.8, 31.34),
    (float('inf'), .82, 33.32),
)
HYDROREELS['50'] = (
    (1.74, 1.23, 24.73),
    (float('inf'), -0.42, 25.68),
)
HYDROREELS['30'] = (
    (1.16, 1.90, 10.57),
    (float('inf'), 2.26, 10.26),
)


def speed(hydroreel, spin):
    """this is the function that calculates the speed from the spins of the hydroreel"""
    if spin in {0, ''}:
        return spin
    spin = float(spin)
    spin_1s = spin / 30

    coefficients = HYDROREELS[hydroreel]
    for limit, c0, c1 in coefficients:
        if spin < limit:
            return (c0 + (c1 * spin_1s)) / 100
```

adding a new hydroreel is now as easy as adding a value to the dict

### GUI

Instead of manually adding each label, which can be a real pain when you want to rename something or translate something, you can work with a dict of label names, and a list of entries

```
LABEL_NAMES = {
    'reel_size': 'Reel Size',
    'measurement_interval': 'Seconds of measurement',
    'measure_start': 'Start Measure',
    'measure_save': 'Inserisci misura',
    'measurement_change': "Cambia misura",
    'depth_change': 'Altra profondità',
    'station_number': "Station number",
    'vertical_no': "Vertical n°",
    'depth_total': 'Total depth',
    'hydroreel_distance': "Hydro reel distance",
    'station_change': "Cambia stazione",
}

ENTRIES = ['station_number', 'vertical_no', 'depth_total', 'hydroreel_distance']
```

Now the class with the GUI

```
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = gui()

        self._populate()

        self.current_file = ''
        self.mis_0 = 0
        self.l = []
```

Here we use the instance variables `current_file`, `l` and `mis_0` instead of the global variables in your version

and instead of doing all the adding of the buttons and labels in the global namespace, we have a populate method

```
def _populate(self):

    self.app.setTitle('Water app')
    self.app.setFont(size=12, family='Calibri')

    self.app.addLabel('l1', 'Measures', 0, 0)
    self.app.addLabel('l2', 'Speed', 5, 0)

    self.app.addLabelOptionBox(LABEL_NAMES['reel_size'], HYDROREELS.keys(), 5, 1)
    self.app.addLabelOptionBox(LABEL_NAMES['measurement_interval'], ['15', '30', '60', '120', '180'], 6, 1, 2)

    self.app.setLabelFont(size=13, weight='bold')
    self.app.setGuiPadding(15, 5)

    for i, entry in enumerate(ENTRIES, 1):
        self.app.addEntry(entry, i, 0)
        self.app.setEntryRelief(entry, 'raised')
        self.app.setEntryDefault(entry, LABEL_NAMES[entry])

    self.app.addLabel('current_speed', "", 6, 0)
    self.app.setEntryWidths(ENTRIES, 20)

    self.app.addButton(LABEL_NAMES['measure_start'], self.start_measure, 6, 0)
    self.app.addButton(LABEL_NAMES['measure_save'], self.save_measure, 4, 1)
    self.app.addButton(LABEL_NAMES['depth_change'], self.change_depth, 3, 1)
    self.app.addButton(LABEL_NAMES['measurement_change'], self.clear_entries, 2, 1)
    self.app.addButton(LABEL_NAMES['station_change'], self.change_station, 1, 1)
    self.app.addButtons([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['0', '.', 'O']], self.press, 1, 2, 3,
                        4)
    self.app.addButtons(
        [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['I', 'L', 'M', 'N'], ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'],
         ['T', 'U', 'V', 'Z']],
        self.press, 1, 5, 4, 5)
```

Off course this method can be split into smaller, methods which are easier to grasp and improve.

As you can see, the labels are replaced by the value in the `LABEL_NAMES`, and the manual sizes of the hydro_reels is taken from the keys of `HYDROREELS`, and the `e1` etc. are replaced by more descriptive labels, placed in a list

### fields

```
def file_name(self):  #
    """Station where you do the measures have a code, and we call the filename with that code"""
    return self.app.getEntry(ENTRIES[0]) + '.csv'
```

### clear entries

since we have the entries in a list now, clearing them all becomes as simple as

```
def change_station(self):  #
    """Clears all entries, when you change station"""
    entries = ENTRIES
    for entry in entries:
        self.app.clearEntry(entry)
    self.app.clearLabel('current_speed')
    self.app.showButton(LABEL_NAMES['measure_start'])
    self.app.setFocus(entries[0])
```

The complete code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vadella/2aa96874af45a48982ee2fae20827ee4)

and is called like this

```
app = MyGUI()
app.go()
```

There are still a lot of options to make this code cleaner and avoid some repitition, but this puts you on the path already

Comment: in regards to `app = MyGUI()` `app.go()` - you even don't need that, just `MyGUI().go()`.